# Ionic 2 Upload file from browser

Tags: file, ionic-framework, file-upload, browser, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 PWA, so it should run in the browser. I want that the user can upload a file to the server. Because the file chooser from ionic native is only for android, I can't use it in browser. So my idea was to use an input field with type="file". But my problem is, that I'm only getting the file name and not the path. And to upload the file I need the path. At first I have tried it with ngModel and then with the form builder from ionic. This is my code with the form builder:

TS:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-test',
    templateUrl: 'test.html',
})
export class TestPage {

    private file : FormGroup;

    constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) {
        this.file = this.formBuilder.group({
            image: ['']
        });
    }

    logForm(){
        console.log(this.file.value)
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
...
<ion-content padding>
    <form [formGroup]="file" (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
        <input type="file" size="50" formControlName="image">
        <button ion-button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

But like I said, the console only logs the filename:

> Object { image: "2970.jpg" }

And if I log "this.file" (without .value) I find there neither a file object or something like this. Is there a way to get the file path in an ionic browser app to upload it to a server?

Comment: did you try my solution? If it worked please accept my answer...

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you already found a solution but I will publish it anyway...

For this solution you don't need any external npm module. Here is step-by-step

Create new component by running

```
$ ionic generate component file-uploader
```

Then copy and paste the code below

**src/components/file-uploader/file-uploader.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

/**
 * Usage
 *
 *  <file-uploader [apiUrl]="apiUrl" [params]="uploadParams"></file-uploader>
 *
 *  <file-uploader [apiUrl]="apiUrl" [params]="[{'key':'language_code', 'value': 'en'}]"></file-uploader>
 *
 */

@Component({
selector: 'file-uploader',
templateUrl: 'file-uploader.html'
})
export class FileUploaderComponent
{
    @ViewChild('file') fileInput: ElementRef;

    @Input('apiUrl') apiUrl: string = null;

    @Input('params') params: Array<{key: string, value: string}> = [];

    @Input('buttonText') buttonText: string = 'Upload';

    @Input('buttonType') buttonType: 'button' | 'icon' = 'icon';

    @Input('icon') icon: string = 'cloud-upload';

    @Input('onUploadSuccess') onUploadSuccess: (file: File, response: any) => void
        = function (file: File, response: any) { console.log(file); console.log(response); };

    @Input('onUploadError') onUploadError: (file: File) => void = function (error: any) { console.log(error) };

    fileToUpload: File = null;

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient)
    {
    }

    triggerFileInputClick()
    {
        this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
    }

    onFileInputChange(files: FileList)
    {
        this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);

        if (this.fileInput.nativeElement.value != '')
        {
            this.upload();
        }
    }

    upload()
    {
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();

        formData.append('file', this.fileToUpload, this.fileToUpload.name);

        this.params.map(param => {
            formData.append(param.key, param.value);
        });

        let headers = {};

        this.httpClient
            .post(this.apiUrl, formData, { headers: headers })
            // .map(() => { return true; })
            .subscribe(response => {
                this.onUploadSuccess(this.fileToUpload, response);

                this.fileInput.nativeElement.value = '';
            }, error => {
                this.onUploadError(error);
            });
    }
}
```

**src/components/file-uploader/file-uploader.html**

```
<div>

    <input type="file" #file (change)="onFileInputChange($event.target.files)">

    <button *ngIf="buttonType == 'button'" ion-button (click)="triggerFileInputClick()">{{buttonText}}</button>

    <ion-icon *ngIf="buttonType == 'icon'" name="cloud-upload" (click)="triggerFileInputClick()"></ion-icon>

</div>
```

**src/components/file-uploader/file-uploader.scss**

```
file-uploader {
    [type=file] {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**src/pages/home/home.html**

```
<file-uploader [apiUrl]="apiUrl" [params]="[{'key':'language_code', 'value': languageCode}]"></file-uploader>
```

All you need to do now is load the component in the NgModule and use it.

Last thing I should mention is if you have problems with undefined attributes e.g. apiUrl, you should initialize them in the ngOnInit() method.

Hope that helps

**UPDATE**
Don't forget to import file uploader into the component that is using uploader or else you'll get **Can't bind to 'apiUrl' since it isn't a known property of 'file-uploader'** error.
What I did is I created new module components.module.ts file in the components folder. Then I imported file uploader component into it. To use it I imported components module into the component that is using the file uploader component.

**src/components/components.module.ts**

```
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FileUploaderComponent } from './file-uploader/file-uploader';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        FileUploaderComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        FileUploaderComponent
    ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

**src/pages/home/home.module.ts**

```
import { ComponentsModule } from '../../components/components.module';
```

Comment: getting error ......Can't bind to 'apiUrl' since it isn't a known property of 'file-uploader'.
1. If 'file-uploader' is an Angular component and it has 'apiUrl' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'file-uploader' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
  <file-uploader [ERROR ->][apiUrl]="apiUrl" [params]="[{'key':'language_code', 'value': languageCode}]">